# PHP CLI script to login an application

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script to log in to a web application using a PHP CLI script:

```
   <?php
     $post_data = array(
    'user_name' => 'abc',
    'user_password'=>'XYZ@@11',
);

$url ='http://www.myapplication.com?action=Login&module=Users';                 
$hat = new  HttpRequest($url,HTTP_METH_POST);
$hat->setPostFields($post_data);
    $hat->send();
    $res = $hat->getResponseData();
    print'<pre>'; print_r($res); print '</pre>';
   ?>
```

I want to post the username and password to this page and try to log in to the application.
I dont know if this is the right way to do this?
Please suggest how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [cURL library](http://is.php.net/curl) to create a POST request.

- [POST data manipulation using php and CURL](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html)
- [Using cURL and libcurl with PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1081-Using-cURL-and-libcurl-with-PHP)

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are accessing uses HTTP Basic authentication, take a look at [HttpRequest::setOptions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-setoptions.php) and set the *httpauth*  and  *httpauthtype* options on your request. You'll need something like this:

```
$options=array();
$options['httpauth']="abc:XYZ@@11";
$options['httpauthtype']=HTTP_AUTH_BASIC;

$hat->setOptions($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine - I don't know much about HttpRequest but you may need to do some work to maintain cookie data, so you stay logged in